# How do I write Ajax syntax to retrieve data from an SQL database

Tags: javascript, ajax, model-view-controller

I am trying to retrieve a particular column in my SQL database using Ajax, Javascript to a button without refreshing the whole page but only the button. I am new to Javascript and AJAX. How can I achieve that. I am using MVC.

```
    function GetId()
    {
        $("#display").onclick(function(){
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "Default.asp/Connection",
            data: "{}",
            dataType: "json",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            success: OnSuccess,
            error:OnError,

            success: function(data){
                displaybuttonFromDatabase();
            }
        });

    }
    function OnSuccess(data){
        var TableContent = "<table border = '0'>" +
                        "<tr>" +
                            "<td>Employee_Identification_No</td>" +
                        "</tr>";

        for(var i = 0; i<data.d.length;i++)
        {
            TableContent += "<tr>" +
                                "<td>" + data.d[i].Employee_Identification_No + "</td>" +
                                "<td></td>" +
                            "</tr>";

        }

        TableContent += "</table>";

        $("#UpdatePanel").html(TableContent);

    }
    function OnError(data) {

    }

    function displaybuttonFromDatabase() {
        $.ajax({
            url: "server",
            type: "POST",
            asyn: false,
            data: {
                "display": 1
            },
            success: function(data){
                $("#display").html(data);
            }
        })
    }
    });
```

I have also tried activating the button upon the click event. Tried this code

```
 function loadmyStaffData()
    {
      var name = document.getElementById("Employee_Identification_No");

       if (name != null)
        {
            $.ajax({
                type: 'post',
                url: '',
                data: {
                    Employee_Identification_No: name,
                },
                success: function(response){
                    $('#display').Html(response);
                }
            });
        }
        else
        {
            $('display').html('Re click this box')
        }
    }
```

Comment: ...and when you try each of these methods, what goes wrong, exactly? What error do you get (check your browser's console, by pressing F12). There are two different scenarios here - in the first one, it loads after a previous ajax call, in the second, it loads when the function "loadmyStaffData" is called (which you say happens when something unspecified is clicked). Which scenario do you actually want? P.S. In the first scenario, your ajax call has two "success" callbacks defined, which is not valid. The second one will probably overwrite the first, I would guess.

Comment: also "asyn: false" is invalid - "asyn" doesn't exist, it should be "async". and specifying it false has no effect because that's the default, so you can just leave it out. Your two different "load button" attempts use different `url` parameters and different data parameters. Ensure you've set the correct parameter vals before continuing. Another point: you should get into the habit of specifying an "error" callback for your ajax calls, so you can a) log errors easily to the console in a format of your choosing, and b) provide meaningful feedback to your users when a call fails for any reason.

Comment: Also, in the second scenario, "name", if not null/undefined, will be a complex object representing an entire HTML element. Are you expecting that it will send a string showing the display text of the element? Depending what kind of element "Employee_Identification_No" is, you might want to use `name.value` or `name.innerText`.